# va_list value is always -52 and crashes using strings

Tags: c++, std, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use the multiple parameters but it doesn't work.
This is the code where the problem should be and which accepts the parameters.

```
void CLog::Write(char lvl, char id, const std::string& sMsg, ...)
{
    FASSERT(m_pLogger != nullptr);

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, sMsg);
    char szBuf[1024];
    vsprintf(szBuf, sMsg.c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);

    m_pLogger->Write(lvl, id, szBuf);
}
```

Using this code when I call

```
CLog::Write(FLOG_LVL_INFO, FLOG_ID_APP, "Vertices: %u", m_vertices.size() );
```

this outputs

```
2013-11-30 - 15:02:45 -  INFO   - Vertices: 3435973836
```

And when I try to pass more strings like this

```
const char * fragment_file_path = "My shader path"; // some path to shader
CLog::Write(FLOG_LVL_INFO, FLOG_ID_APP, "Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
```

then the program crashes and gives this

```
Unhandled exception at 0x560616B3 (msvcr110d.dll) in Fabian.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

I've compared the code with other examples and checked the reference again for [va_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/) and [vsprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/) but I can't seem to find waths wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with g++: http://ideone.com/WYrUjd

Comment: As you're using C++11, variadic templates are preferred.

Comment: @chris never seen that before but looks interesting. I'm going to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to initializing `fragment_file_path`, `va_arg` does `sizeof` in its implementation, and `sizeof(sMsg)` will be `sizeof(string)` to figure out where the next argument starts on the stack, which is wrong because `sMsg` is a *reference* to a string, not a string.

You cannot use references as the last named parameter with varargs; use values or pointers.

Comment: well the `sMsg` in the `vsprintf` is `sMsg.c_str()` which is a `const char*` so it is actually a pointer

Comment: @g-makulik `va_start` gets passed the last named parameter because real-world implementations needed to take its address, add the size, fix up the alignment, in order to access the unnamed parameters. Only on compilers where `va_start` is implemented as a built-in can it possibly work with references, and I'm not aware of such a requirement.

Comment: my bad I didn't read it correct, the problem is indeed that the last parameter is a reference. I've changed it to `const char*` and now it works